# Python 3 - use urllib to run .jsp script and retrieve results

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, post, urllib

I have a csv file that is created everytime I run a .jsp file on a Tomcat server. When done manually I click on a link "servers.jsp" and a file "server_list.csv" starts downloading.

I would like to do this in a Python v3 script so I can iterate over the results and automate the process.

here is my code to send a POST to the server, pass auth values in the url and receive the generated .csv

```
import urllib.request

link = "https://tomcat.server.org:8443/html/scripts/servers.jsp"
userpass = {'pass': '12345', 'user': 'admin'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(userpass)
data = data.encode('utf-8') 
req = urllib.request.Request(link, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

saveFile = open(Myfile.csv,'w')
saveFile.write(str(respData))
saveFile.close()
```

- A file is indeed created but it is not the full file only the first row( or parts of) of what the file should contain. Why doesn't the whole file get downloaded ?
- How can i print as a string the value of `urllib.request.urlopen(req)` ?

Note: I can not use any module that does not come with the default distro of Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `urllib.request.urlretrieve` instead?

https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve

NOTE: If the URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy of the object exists, the object is not copied

On a side note, take a look at `requests` package which is a nice wrapper built around `urllib`. I find it easier to use.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: The question states he doesn't want to use outside packages. (`requests`)

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check response code `resp.code`. If it's 200, you can get the content by calling `resp.readall` which reads until EOF and returns `bytes`.

It `resp.getheader('Content-type')` is some kinda text, you can display with `print(str(resp.readall())`. If `Content-type` is non-text you have to store it to a file. Because the content is `bytes`, it has to be stored in a file `open`ed in binary mode.

```
respData = resp.readall()
with open(Myfile.csv,'wb') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(respData)
```